# Can I ignore Java compiler warnings in generated code?

Tags: java, android, compiler-warnings, android-databinding

I'm using Data Binding on Android, which automatically generates code classes in order to bind views to data. 
Unfortunately, the compiler flags a warning inside the generated code:

```
/app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/com/test/databinding/TestFragmentBindingImpl.java:56: warning: [cast] redundant cast to boolean
                vm.setEnabled(((boolean) (callbackArg_0)));
                                        ^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
1 error
```

I'm required to have 0 warnings in my project, so I'm using -Werror. 
I can't just add `@SuppressWarnings` to the generated class, and I don't want to `-Xlint:-cast` for the entire project.

How can I ignore warnings in generated classes?